# Named Pipes passing Object, End of Stream issues

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming, named-pipes

I am trying to pass a class object via Named pipes in C#. However I get an Error "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed" . 
This is really frustrating since, I've managed to send strings without problems. Does anyone can see what is the issue?

Client Side Sending Data:

```
using(NamedPipeClientStream cs = 
    new NamedPipeClientStream("MyServer", "MyPipeName", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
{
    ObservableCollection<MyObject> messageToSend = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(new MyObject() { MyProp1 = "Hello", MyProp2 = 7 });
    IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
    foreach (var item in messageToSend)
    {
        f.Serialize(pipeStream, item);
    }
}
```

Server Side Receiving the Data:

```
NamedPipeServerStream ss = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipeName", PipeDirection.In);
ss.WaitForConnection();
IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
MyObject messageReceived = (MyObject)f.Deserialize(cs);
```

Also, when I add to the receiver I've got another error "Stream does not support seeking".

```
ss.Position =0;
```

The class used as the message type:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject
{
    public string MyProp1 { get; set; }
    public int MyProp2 { get; set; }
}
```